# Does mastering a foreign language strengthen the pre-frontal cortex?

Tags: social-cognition

Main Question:
Does mastering a foreign language strengthen the pre-frontal cortex?
I remember taking a Cognition class, that claimed mastering a foreign language improves the brains higher functioning ability, and stimulates the pre-frontal cortex.

Thank you for your time,
David L Blass.

Comment: What do you mean with 'strengthen'?

Comment: Please refrain from asking the same question multiple times. I have deleted your two similar follow-up posts. You can edit this one to improve it based on the feedback you have already received from the community. When you do, it could be eligible for reopening.